# SQL join query with count operation

Tags: mysql

hey everyone i have a database that has the following tables

students table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Studeni_ID | Firstname | Lastname | Contact    |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
|          1 | Deen      | Nute     |   85124512 |
|          2 | Helen     | Jude     | 2147483647 |
|          3 | Howard    | Mindy    |    8965123 |
+------------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

first_exam table:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
| Studeni_ID | Subject_Name | Score | Year | Term |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
|          1 | English      |    54 | 2015 |    1 |
|          1 | Math         |    48 | 2014 |    2 |
|          1 | History      |    85 | 2015 |    1 |
|          2 | English      |    59 | 2015 |    1 |
|          2 | Math         |    65 | 2015 |    1 |
|          3 | English      |    59 | 2015 |    1 |
|          2 | science      |    41 | 2015 |    1 |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
```

last_exam table:

```
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
| Studeni_ID | Subject_Name | Score | Year | Term |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
|          1 | English      |    75 | 2015 |    1 |
|          2 | English      |    86 | 2015 |    1 |
|          3 | History      |    72 | 2015 |    1 |
+------------+--------------+-------+------+------+
```

i am trying to get the count of all exams taken by each student in the year 2015 and term 1 so here are the queries i have tried and their outputs:

```
SELECT First_Exam.Studeni_ID, student.Firstname, student.Lastname, 
COUNT(First_Exam.Subject_Name)AS FirstE,
COUNT(Last_Exam.Subject_Name)AS LAST_E 
FROM student,First_Exam,Last_Exam  
WHERE student.Studeni_ID=First_Exam.Studeni_ID=Last_Exam.Studeni_ID 
AND First_Exam.Year=2015 AND First_Exam.Term=1 
AND Last_Exam.Year=2015 AND Last_Exam.Term=1 
GROUP BY First_Exam.Studeni_ID;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
| Studeni_ID | Firstname | Lastname | FirstE | LAST_E |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
|          1 | Deen      | Nute     |      2 |      2 |
|          2 | Helen     | Jude     |      3 |      3 |
|          3 | Howard    | Mindy    |      1 |      1 |
+------------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
```

and

```
SELECT First_Exam.Studeni_ID, student.Firstname, student.Lastname, COUNT(First_Exam.Subject_Name)AS First_E,COUNT(Last_Exam.Subject_Name)AS Last_E FROM First_Exam 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.Studeni_ID=First_Exam.Studeni_ID 
INNER JOIN Last_Exam 
ON First_Exam.Studeni_ID=Last_Exam.Studeni_ID 
WHERE First_Exam.Year=2015 AND First_Exam.Term=1 AND Last_Exam.Year=2015 AND Last_Exam.Term=1 GROUP BY First_Exam.Studeni_ID ;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
| Studeni_ID | Firstname | Lastname | First_E | Last_E |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
|          1 | Deen      | Nute     |       2 |      2 |
|          2 | Helen     | Jude     |       3 |      3 |
|          3 | Howard    | Mindy    |       1 |      1 |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+--------+
```

they all have errors in their output can anyone please help me solve this issue....

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: Group by with `first name` and `last name` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Join the student table and first exam table, and sum the rows only when year and term is as you said, this will gaurentee that all students from student table would come, even if they have not done any test.
Then i would union that with the same format last exam.

Why is there 2 tables with the same structure, you can store them in the same table.

Then finally i sum the value from the union of the two tables group by student id .

The below query should work

```
select Studeni_ID, sum(cnt) FROM (
select Studeni_ID , SUM(case when year = 2015  then 1 else 0 end) cnt FROM students left join first_exam on students.Studeni_ID  = first_exam.Studeni_ID group by students.Studeni_ID
union
select Studeni_ID , SUM(case when year = 2015  then 1 else 0 end) cnt FROM students left join last_exam on students.Studeni_ID  = last_exam.Studeni_ID group by students.Studeni_ID
) group by Studeni_ID
```

Comment: thakyou for the advice and solution though i found that using the Distinct key word also works     SELECT First_Exam.Studeni_ID, student.Firstname, student.Lastname, COUNT(Distinct First_Exam.Subject_Name)AS First_E,COUNT(Distinct Last_Exam.Subject_Name)AS Last_E FROM First_Exam 
INNER JOIN student 
ON student.Studeni_ID=First_Exam.Studeni_ID 
INNER JOIN Last_Exam 
ON First_Exam.Studeni_ID=Last_Exam.Studeni_ID 
WHERE First_Exam.Year=2015 AND First_Exam.Term=1 AND Last_Exam.Year=2015 AND Last_Exam.Term=1 GROUP BY First_Exam.Studeni_ID ;